# Salesforce object into Excel query issue - Expression. Error The module named XXX has been disabled in this context

Tags: jquery, excel, object, salesforce, expression

[image]I have been changing my approach of late to start to learn Getting data into Exel from external sources.

I have created an excel (can't share at mo as has sensitive data in it), that I have added Salesforce Opportunity object to it and then transformed to get the info I need on the sheet.

I can go into the spreadsheet, refresh everything and it all works... BUT

### A colleague who is using the same file (saved on Teams folder) get the error

### Alert
[Expression.Error] The module names 'Salesforce" has been disabled in this context
OK

I am not sure where to start digging and not found anything on google yet.
All ideas appreciated

Was expecting, that anyone who can open the file would be able to use it.

The file is shared with them and error below.

Thanks for taking the time to read and hopefully help
G